# What's the most appropriate exception to throw if a required app/web.config configuration setting is not present?

Tags: .net, exception, configuration, web-config, app-config

(Asked by @tomhollander on Twitter)
What's the most appropriate exception to throw if a required app/web.config configuration setting is not present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ConfigurationException** is obsolete. The docs say it's been replaced by **ConfigurationErrorsException**, but this is designed to convey failures in the configuration system - I don't believe it's intended to show problems such as missing or malformed configuration values.

Answer (score 7):

[System.Configuration.ConfigurationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationexception.aspx)

According to MSDN (emphasis added by me):

> The ConfigurationException exception
>   is thrown if the application attempts
>   to read or write data to the
>   configuration file but is
>   unsuccessful. Some possible reasons
>   for this can include malformed XML in
>   the configuration file, file
>   permission issues, and **configuration
>   properties with values that are not
>   valid**.

Comment: From the same article, though:

Note
The ConfigurationException object is maintained for backward compatibility. The ConfigurationErrorsException object replaces it for the configuration system.